# png terminal not working gnuplot in OS X 10.8.4

Tags: macos, gnuplot

I have started using gnuplot in my macbook pro. I am using OS X 10.8.4. Whenever I set terminal to png using

> set term png

it gave an error as follow:
unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list

Does somebody know it?

Comment: How have you installed gnuplot? Usually this error indicates missing libraries (or links to libraries).

Comment: Yes, I installed gnuplot from source. In addition, following suggestions for blogs, I also installed the libraries for png independently. Still, it did not work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe [this explanation](https://mailman.cae.wisc.edu/pipermail/help-octave/2005-August/017633.html) is useful.

Comment: A similar issue has been discussed over at the [Apple exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/cant-plot-with-gnuplot-on-my-mac), which may be of some help.